# Snort / PulledPork event filter via modifysid.conf not filtering traffic

Tags: snort

I'm using SecurityOnion with Snort/PulledPork/Snorby. I am getting multiple "ET POLICY Pandora Usage" alerts a minute for the same source and destination. I want to threshold these to get 1 alert per day per source.

The original rule:

alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"ET POLICY Pandora Usage"; flow:established,to_server; content:"POST"; http_method; content:"/radio/xmlrpc/"; http_uri; content:"pandora.com|0d 0a|"; http_header; threshold: type threshold, track by_src, count 1, seconds 3600; reference:url,www.pandora.com; classtype:policy-violation; sid:2014997; rev:1;)

I have edited modifysid.conf in etc/nsm/pulledpork/ to include this line: 2014997 "3600" "43200"

After rule-update, the rule now shows in etc/nsm/rules/downloaded.conf as:

alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"ET POLICY Pandora Usage"; flow:established,to_server; content:"POST"; http_method; content:"/radio/xmlrpc/"; http_uri; content:"pandora.com|0d 0a|"; http_header; threshold: type threshold, track by_src, count 1, second**s 86400; reference:url,www.pandora.com; classtype:policy-violation; sid:2014997; rev:1;)

This is even the correct alert that is pulled into Snorby as I review the rules. I even tried lowering seconds to a 12 hour timeframe.

Nothing has worked, I still get the same number of rules. Why is pulledpork/snort not using the threshold in the rule? What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is purely about using the config settings for an application, not a security question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed they type from "threshold" to "limit" and it seemed to help.